# Android SQLite: order by many columns

Tags: android, sqlite

TABLE_NAME (COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4);

```
     Cursor cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, COL1);
```

This way we get the entries ordered by COL1 values. If some of them has the same COL1  value SQLite uses the same order as when they were stored by the previous insertions.

Is it possible to define many degrees of sorting? For example, if two or more entries has the same COL1 value then the one with the smaller COL2 value will go first and so on.

Android site says that we can specify only a String (column) for the sorting.

```
query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

If I use a

```
 db.rawQuery("sql code")
```

the string of sql code will be compiled at runtime so the program will be slower. I would like to avoid that if not necessary. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With String orderBy you could specify multiple columns as this:

```
String order = COL1 + ", " +COL2 + ", " + COL3;
Cursor cur = db.query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, order);
```

Comment: thank you! I thought it was mandatory the use of a String[] type to specificy more columns.